# Running a Python script with and without "python"

Tags: python, windows

I've noticed a somewhat strange behavior when running a python script on Windows with and without the word "python".

My script:
`print "Command line arguments:", sys.argv`
`print "Command line arguments length", len(sys.argv)`

When I run `try.py 1 2 3 4` I get:
`Command line arguments: ['C:\\PythonTemp\\try.py']`
`Command line arguments length 1`

Which is obviously wrong...

But when I run `python try.py 1 2 3 4` I get the expected result:
`Command line arguments: ['try.py', '1', '2', '3', '4']`
`Command line arguments length 5`

Can you please explain why this happens?